# Databinding Container documentation

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I usually use expressions like this

```
CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex.ToString() %> '
```

But I could not find Container in the msdn, can u help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Container` is a keyword that is only applicable to data binding expressions and is a reference to the naming container.

See this from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858twd77.aspx) (How to: Access Members of a Control's Naming Container):

> In the data-binding expression, use the Container keyword, which returns a reference to the container.

And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txxbk90b.aspx) (Using the NamingContainer Property to Determine a Control's Naming Container):

> ... the Container keyword, which is available only in inline code (that is, in a declarative <%#   %> expression) ...

Answer (score 1):

Container is usually represented by an object implementing the INamingContainer interface.  However, this is not a strict rule.  You can read about this in the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx(VS.71).aspx

If you want to know the type of the Container object, I would suggest that you use the following approach:

define the following binding expression:

```
CommandArgument='<%# GetCommandArgument(Container)%>
```

and also define the following method in the page's code:

```
protected string GetCommandArgument(object container)  {
  return string.Empty;
}
```

Set the breakpoint in the page's method and check the container's type in the QuickWatch.  Hope, this helps...